# Is it okay to expose payment API client side public key to be exposed in source code?

Tags: javascript, api, public-key

I am writing plain html css and javascript for payment system. I have public_key for client side to initiate payment,

```
var config = {
// replace the publicKey with yours
"publicKey": "test_public_key_......",
"productIdentity": "1001",
"productName": "Course Purchse ",
"productUrl": "http://shikxya.com",
"paymentPreference": [
    "EBANKING",
    "MOBILE_BANKING"
],
"eventHandler": {
    onSuccess(payload) {
        // hit merchant api for initiating verfication
        console.log(payload);

        const payemtRequst = payload;
        var amount = payload['amount'];
        var idx = payload['token'];

        window.location.href = "payment.php?amount="+amount+"&idx="+idx;


    },
    onError(error) {
        console.log(error);
    },
    onClose() {
        console.log('widget is closing');
    }
}
```

};

On source code of given page publick_key is clearly shown, is it okay ? Or is there any way to hide it from source code so that from client side is it impossible to see publik_key ?

Comment: Any sensitive data, like api keys, credentials, payment info, etc. should be obscured from the client's view. The best way to do this is to store that information on the server side.

Comment: Is there any way here hiding it ?

Comment: A public key is not sensitive data. It's called a 'public' key for that reason, namely that it should be made public. It's the corresponding private key that must remain secret.